# Flask Assertion Error using multiple blueprints

Tags: python, rest, flask

EDIT: So after a little more digging it seems the problem (if it is a problem, it is likely intentional for reasons beyond my comprehension) is with Flask-Cognito (lib I'm using to handle User Authtentication via AWS) - many of my routes have the decorators `@cognito_auth_required` and `@cognito_group_permissions(['admin'])` but it seems I can't apply this to more than 1 route per blueprint. However multiple routes on the blueprints need to be restricted to admin users only. Is there a way I can apply these decorators across multiple routes?

Code updated to provide context.

-- end edit --

apologies if this is a noob question, I'm fairly new to Flask.

I am writing a RESTful API, I am registering multiple blueprints in an attempt to keep code clean however, I keep receiving `AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: products.wrapper` message when trying to run my program locally. This error only started popping up when I implemented my second blueprint.

All blueprints are registered as so:

```
api_base_url = '/api/v1'
app.register_blueprint(products, url_prefix=api_base_url+'/products')
app.register_blueprint(categories, url_prefix=api_base_url+'/categories')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = app
    application.debug = True
    application.run()
```

And in my `routes.py` file:

```
.. code omitted, Product + Category models imported from models ... 

@products.route('/create', methods=['POST'])
@cognito_auth_required
@cognito_group_permissions(['admin'])
def products_create():
    # code omitted for readability
    return jsonify(error=False, message='New product created')
    
@categories.route('/create', methods=['POST'])
@cognito_auth_required
@cognito_group_permissions(['admin'])
def categories_create():
    # code omitted for readability
    return jsonify(error=False, message='New category created')
```

Initially I had had the routes both point to two different `def all():` functions but I changed it in the hope that multiple functions with the same name was the problem, to no avail. I'm not sure what could be causing this endpoint conflict - each blueprint has their own URL prefix so it should mitigate endpoint collision but perhaps this is not the case? Is it possible, since the blueprints are registered just before the program spins up, that it hasn't prepended the URL prefixes before checking for collisions?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured it out - it seems the decorator `@cognito_group_permissions` doesn't wrap the function. In order to get it working I created `decorators.py` imported wraps from `functools` and ammended the code from flask_cognito:

Original:

```
def cognito_check_groups(groups: list):
    def decorator(function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            _cognito_check_groups(groups)
            return function(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

Decorators.py:

```
from functools import wraps
from flask_cognito import _cognito_check_groups

def cognito_in_groups(groups: list):
    def decorator(function):
        @wraps(function)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            _cognito_check_groups(groups)
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Then I imported into my routes and used the updated decorator and now all works perfectly:

```
from decorators import cognito_in_groups
@products.route('/create', methods=['POST'])
@cognito_auth_required
@cognito_in_groups(['admin'])
def products_create():
    try:
        # code omitted...
        return jsonify(error=False, message='New product created')
    except IntegrityError:
        return jsonify(error=True, message='Duplicate SKU detected')
```

Leaving here in case anyone else runs into a similar problem.

Curious that cognito_auth_required is wrapped but cognito_check_groups isn't, if anyone could shed light on the reasons for this I'd would be interested to know.

Cheers